# change localhost domain when running locally

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2008, iis

I am using Visual studio as my IDE is developing a .net web application.

I use my local IIS7 web server to run the application.

It runs under the url -> http://localhost/AppName/

I want the change this to -> http://localhost.appname.com/AppName/

I have added the following host file entry 
127.0.0.1 localhost.appname.com

This now mean I can access the site via http://localhost.appname.com/AppName/ like I wanted.

I have one issue though, if I run the site via "Start Debugging" (F5), the site runs in the domain http://localhost/AppName/ .

What changes do I need to make to the web application to get it to start with domain http://localhost.appname.com/AppName/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The startup page can be set via project properties => web. Typically I find the best option is "do nothing" (I'll invoke the page I want in the browser I want manually)

Comment: ♦, I need to set up a fake domain like the one above so that others may test it in their own Visual Studio without having to change their host file. Is this even possible? Please check the question:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6208172/use-fake-domain-locally-in-visual-studio-without-modifying-the-host-file-directly Thanks!