# Use fake domain locally in Visual Studio without modifying the host file directly

Tags: asp.net, iis

I have an application that runs here http://localhost:10205/ but I need it run locally as http://somethingelse.com/.

This needs to happen on other computers as well without the need to alter the host file.

How do I do that?

Comment: Should be on ServerFault or possibly SuperUser.

Comment: How do I migrate this question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are all within the same network, you can add an A Record to your domain controller.  Beyond that, there's not much you can do when you're dealing with multiple endpoints.  As far as actually performing that task, you may want to discuss on serverfault.