# Can I change locally running application domain name 'localhost' to say 'abcd'

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, iis-7.5

while running asp.net application locally, the domain name shows 'http://localhost:50984/application1/'
Can I change 'localhost' to 'abcd'? if yes how?
how can this application be made available through network to other computers?

(I am using Visual Web Developer 2010 Express, windows 7) (I found some similar kind of questions like [change localhost domain when running locally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4270516/change-localhost-domain-when-running-locally) but didn't find any way to implement)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Open up your hosts file and modify 'localhost' to 'abcd', which is located at `C:\Windows\System 32\drivers\etc\hosts` (you'll have to open with notepad).

In order allow your application to be accessed on other computers you'll have to host it somewhere. This usually means within [IIS](http://www.iis.net/overview) because as far as I know this isn't currently possible with the local server provided with Web Developer 2010 Express.

Comment: but when VWD runs, it uses localhost only..how to change it?

Comment: You might have to restart the browser for the hosts file to take effect.  Have you tried 'abcd' by typing in manually?  If this works and localhost doesn't there will be setting in VS.

Comment: I tried manually typing and its working.. what setting? how to change it?

Comment: I don't know the exact setting, try looking about or use google.

Comment: how to know the IP address of the current running application? ie.,there are two entries--- "127.0.0.1       localhost" and "::1             localhost" ---how can I identify that which IP for which application? and also, what is "::1"? is it also an IP address?